# How to connect Hive to asp.net project

Tags: c#, hadoop, hbase, hive, azure-hdinsight

Hi I'm very new to Hadoop.

I have installed Microsoft HDInsight to my local system.
Now I want to connect to hive and HBase but for HIVE connection 
I have to specify Connection string, port, username, password.

But I'm not able to figure out how I will get this value. 
I have tried with localhost and 8085 as a port but this doesn't work.
I also done it by giving localhost IP and my system IP too.

Please help with this and let me know how i should proceed for HBase connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to use [Microsoft's Hive SDK](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/) (also available on nuget as Microsoft.Hadoop.Hive)

There is a great sample on how to connect and run a Linq-to-Hive query at
http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Simple%20Linq%20To%20Hive%20Query&referringTitle=LINQ%20to%20Hive

This used the WebHcat API to submit your query to Hive, and will work against an HDInsights cluster in the Azure cloud (hence the need to provide a storage key to get the results back again).

If you're only interested in using the local copy you can adapt the example to exclude the storage account credentials.

```
var db = new HiveConnection(
            webHCatUri: new Uri("http://localhost:50111"),
            userName: (string) "hadoop", password: (string) null);

var result = db.ExecuteHiveQuery("select * from w3c");
result.Wait();
```

works against a base install of HDInsight Preview.